# See dashboard as non logged user in community

Tags: community, reporting, dashboard, analytics

Is it possible, *as a non logged user*, to see report and dashboard in community when it is open to non logged user? And  for analytic dashboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible for a Salesforce Community Guest User to see Reports or Dashboards from a public Community page. Here's a link to Salesforce documentation talking about Communities Report and Dashboard Considerations, it explains who can have access to Reports/Dashboards in a Community https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_analytics_limitations.htm&type=0.

One thing I have done as a workaround is to create my own report/dashboard using Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API and other third-party data visualizations libraries to expose Salesforce data in a Report/Dashboard-like format as a custom Aura, LWC or Visualforce component, and then exposing that component in a public Community page.